# Python filter function - single result

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

Is there a built in function in Python that will return a single result given a list and a validation function?

For example I know I can do the following:

```
    resource = list(filter(lambda x: x.uri == uri, subject.resources))[0]
```

The above will extract a resource from a list of resources, based on ther resource.uri field. Although this field value is uinique, so I know that I will either have 1 or 0 results. `filter` function will iterate the whole list. In my case its 20 elements, but I want to know if there is some other built-in way to stop the iteration on first match.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

> **next(iterator[, default])**
>
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its **next**() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

e.g. in your case:

```
resource = next(filter(lambda x: x.uri == uri, subject.resources), None)
```

Comment: i've been wondering the same thing for so long. thanks :)

Comment: this doesn't seem like answering the problem thoroughly, the field value is said to be unique, so the developer expects 0, or 1 objects at this point, meaning in case of multiple records we should have an error, which this answer won't detect.

I've been wondering about similar thing for a while now, but this doesn't seem to solve problem entirely.

Comment: @tikej then it's validation where you need to iterate the whole list to get the count: `sum(x.uri == uri for x in subject.resources)` or just call above snippet with `next` again.